# How to set system time in a Windows WDM driver?

Tags: c, windows, device-driver, wdm

We are developing a GPS time sychronization hardware device. And we want write a Windows WDM driver for the device. To avoid the user level latency, we'd like set windows( XP/Vista/7) system time in the kernel driver level. Does anyone know how to achive that?

Thanks
Xu Jun

Answer (score 1):

Did you try NtSetSystemTime? I think it's undocumented.

http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/

See also  http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/Time/NtQuerySystemTime.html

Yyou should use the Zw-prefix functions in your driver.